# Concatenate repeating XML fields into 1

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML output file (for a citation) with data that repeats Author when the article has multiple authors, so like this:

```
<Affiliation>a School of Architecture and Urban Planning , Nanjing University , Nanjing , China.</Affiliation>
        <AuthorList CompleteYN="Y">
            <Author ValidYN="Y">
                <LastName>Gao</LastName>
                <ForeName>Zhi</ForeName>
                <Initials>Z</Initials>
            </Author>
            <Author ValidYN="Y">
                <LastName>Zhang</LastName>
                <ForeName>J S</ForeName>
                <Initials>JS</Initials>
            </Author>
            <Author ValidYN="Y">
                <LastName>Byington</LastName>
                <ForeName>Jerry G A</ForeName>
                <Initials>JG</Initials>
            </Author>
        </AuthorList>
        <Language>eng</Language>
```

What I would like to do is end up with a file that joins the authors so that you end up with

```
<Authors>Gao, Z // Zhang, JS // Byington, JG</Authors>
```

So, using the LastName and Initials and adding a separator between them into one field

This is my first time looking at this and xsl so I am hoping someone can suggest how this could be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stylesheet will do what you ask. It copies the entire document except for any `AuthorList` elements, which are transformed as you describe.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AuthorList">
    <Authors>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Author"/>
    </Authors>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Author">
    <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::Author">
      <xsl:text> // </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(LastName, ', ', Initials)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Affiliation>a School of Architecture and Urban Planning , Nanjing University , Nanjing , China.</Affiliation>
   <Authors>Gao, Z // Zhang, JS // Byington, JG</Authors>
   <Language>eng</Language>
</root>
```

Comment: Your solution is a perfectly acceptable one to me, although it is a tad wasteful in some areas (e.g., it is unnecessary to use the `preceding-sibling::` axis).

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in a slightly shorter alternative.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AuthorList">
    <Authors>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </Authors>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Author">
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1"> // </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(LastName, ', ', Initials)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```